# Controling affine transform of raster in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, affine-transformation

I have a png file which I created from a field equation. I need to plot that on my map. I am plotting it on a map with Coordinate System being GCS WGS 1984 (EPSG: 4326).

Since it is not georeferenced, the image comes in with the top left corner at N 0 E 0, which I anticipated. It also comes in with pixel size at 1 degree. I need to affine transform it by specific numbers, and not by clicking control points.

I have looked around online for a way to do this, but I can't find anything. Can someone point me in the right direction?

If necessary, I can do this in ArcGIS Desktop 10 then move it to ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the translation, rotation, and scale tools to transform the data manually. For translation use the "shift" tool, for rotation use "Rotate" and for scaling use "rescale".

Comment: That does it. It takes multiple iterations because it seems like it is getting confused on the rotation point location, so I have to shift it again after I rotate it. But the main thing is, it works.

Comment: Also, the information Pop-up is not aware of the rotation. I mention this in case anyone from ESRI happens to notice. This is based on the layer only. I plan to export the layer to a new raster, and I expect that will provide correct info which clicked upon. (But I haven't done that yet.)